# linear algebra span of four unknown vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

I've just started taking a course in linear algebra and I'm stuck on the last problem of the assignment and I am in need of a hint on how to figure out the solution. Here go the problem:

Let $H_1$=Span{$u_1,u_2$} and $H_2$=Span{$v_1,v_2$} be subsets in $R^3$.

1) show that the vectors {$u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$} are linear dependent.

2)If $H_1$ and $H_2$ are different planes and $v_1∈ H_1$. Show that the intersection $H_1 ∩ H_2$ is the line Span($v_1$)

3) If $H_1$ and $H_2$ are different planes and $v_1∈ H_1$. Show that {$u_1,u_2,v_2$} are linear independent.

4) If $H_1$ and $H_2$ are different planes and $H_1 ∩ H_2 =l$  is a line $L=Span(e)$. Show that three of the vectors {$u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$} are linear independent.

> I feel like I kind of understand all of the exercises but I really don't have an idea on how to mathematically show any of the statements.
>
> The 1) I know how to prove but the rest of them I would really appreciate any form of help. I know how to prove these kind of things when you know the vectors, but not when the vectors are unknown.

Comment: The expected solution to this kind of exercise really depends on the context and what you're currently studying.  For instance, the first question follows immediately from the rank-nullity theorem, but it's probably not the way you're supposed to answer.  You will get the most help if you talk to your instructor.